# Can I consume an AWS MSK kafka topic from a Lambda function?

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I thought it would be trivial to use a lambda to consume messages coming to a topic in a AWS MSK Kafka cluster, but I could not find a way to do it from the AWS docs. Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can by using a Kafka client library in you Lambda code. Find an example for Python below:

```
#!/bin/env python

import json
import logging
import time
import os
from kafka import KafkaConsumer               


"""
Read data from MSK and console it out.

Required environment variables:
MSK_BOOTSTRAP_SRV: MSK Bootstrap servers. 
MSK_TOPIC_NAME: MSK topic. 

"""
kafka_client = None
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.debug('MSK consumer starts.')
    try:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(os.environ['MSK_TOPIC_NAME'], auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                             bootstrap_servers=os.environ['MSK_BOOTSTRAP_SRV'], api_version=(0, 10), consumer_timeout_ms=1000)
        
        for msg in consumer:
            print(msg.value)

        if consumer is not None:
            consumer.close()
            
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error('Exception: {}'.format(ex))
    return
```

Comment: What would trigger the client to consume the topic?

Comment: If you use AWS Lambda, there is already an integration for it. If you use something else, you need the consumer to pull messages from the topic. Programming languages libraries can help you with that.

Comment: Be careful using the Kafka event source (trigger) as suggested by @herbertgoto if you are receiving messages in batches or processing them in a way that is not idempotent.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html#invocation-eventsourcemapping-batching

"When an error occurs, Lambda returns batches to the queue as individual items and might process them in a different grouping than the original batch. Occasionally, the event source mapping might receive the same item from the queue twice, even if no function error occurred"